# tag merge request: everything to do with [google-adwords]

Tags: support, retag-request

If there is a need for specific versions of adwords tags then they should at least follow the same naming scheme, something like [google-adwords-201402](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-adwords-201402).  If they can be gotten rid of, all the better.

[image]

Comment: That's now your 3rd question in a row to clean up tags.  Can't SO have an review for this or something like this. (just an idea)

Comment: @Rizier123: I'm counting five...

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, I counted it from the meta SO start page: http://imgur.com/AEfhmAZ

Comment: I'm walking through all tags to generate a sort of meta tag for use on Careers.  I expect to run across a few more of these throughout the day.  I popped a few of them on internal chat rooms but the suggestion was to go to meta to find users of the tags to comment on the suggestions.